# Congruences in model theory

Tags: model-theory, semigroups

I've begun reading Steinberg's book on representations of finite monoids. In the very first chapter, he introduces congruences on a monoid as an equivalence relation $\equiv$ such that $x \equiv y$ implies $zxw \equiv zyw$ for all $x, y, z, w$ in the monoid. From this arises the quotient monoid $M / \equiv$ with the obvious multiplication.

The associative and identity axioms of this construction are pretty automatic, so that only well-definedness has to be shown. And I believe the proof carries over to semigroups, provided one replaces the condition by $x \equiv y$ implies $zx \equiv zy$ and $xw \equiv yw$ for all $x, y, z, w$ in the monoid.

These conditions both generalise to universal algebra, by taking an equivalence relation that is also a subalgebra of $A \times A$, where $A$ is an algebra with certain operations.

My question is: **Does this generalise to model theory?**

Comment: Yes, for an $n$-ary predicate symbo $R$ we need $x_i\equiv y_i\implies (R(\vec x)\iff R(\vec y))$.

Comment: @Berci That should really be (part of?) an answer.

Comment: The first paragraph of this [Rob Arthan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341731/pa-with-successor-not-being-a-function/348317#348317) answers your question positively.

Comment: Steinberg's definition of a congruence is definitely compact, but doesn't provide much intuition I'm afraid.